# How to Get WooCommerce Product ID from It's Slug?

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

Is it possible to get an `ID` of a WooCommerce product only by knowing it's `slug`? I need to fetch the product's price outside the product's page.

Comment: yes! it;s depend on your slug.

Comment: how? the page i'm in and the target product's page share the same slug.

Comment: can you show slug

Comment: domain.com/product/test is the product. domain.com/course/test is the page i'm in, need to get the id of test product.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

use the existing function get_page_by_path();

```
$product_obj = get_page_by_path( $slug, OBJECT, 'product' );
```

better explanation :

https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/206886/get-product-details-by-url-key-in-wordpress-woocommerce

Comment: If you want the WC_Product object, you can update this a bit:

```$product_obj = new WC_Product(get_page_by_path( $slug, OBJECT, 'product' )->ID);```

Comment: This really helped me out, thanks